# Какие технологии Boost уже были включены в официальную спецификацию C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Какие технологии Boost были включены и реализованы в stdlib C++ 11?

Какие планируется включить?

Почему бы не включать Boost в компиляторы?

Comment: А что мешает любому человеку просто поставить boost точно так же, как и любую другую стороннюю библиотеку?

Comment: @monobogdan  Лично я не считаю, что Boost заслуживает быть включенной в стандарт C++. Более того, я считаю недостатком программиста, если он часто обращается к Boost, так как это порой свидетельствует о не знании C++, когда слабые программисты просто не способны написать код и ищут уже готовые решения без критического подхода к ним.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, не совсем так, ведь Boost ускоряет разработку и помогает решить некоторую рутину(кроссплатформенные потоки, парсер ini(пусть он и пишется за 10 минут) и xml, конвертер типов(смотря каких))

Comment: @monobogdan  Я сейчас не могу найти ссылку на SO, но сюжет вопроса был таким: "Меня попросили написать функцию такую-то, и я нашел в интернет вот такую ее реализацию". И далее приводится просто страшный код. Обратите внимание на слова "Меня попросили НАПИСАТЬ функцию...". То есть программист уже не способен писать код, а ищет решения в интернет и, причем, не в состоянии даже оценить, что он нашел.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, мне нравятся именно кроссплатформенные фичи Boost, и собственно они в основном и включаются в спецификации, правда я незнаю точно какие, поэтому и спросил

Comment: @monobogdan  Когда, например, в описании вакансии указывается требование знания Boost, то это говорит лишь об одном, в этой организации работают крайне низко-квалифицированные программисты. Совершенно НЕ нужно знать Boost. Если вам что-то действительно понадобится оттуда, то вы можете этим воспользоваться по мере необходимости в процессе работы.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, но ведь некоторые полезные классы Boost уже включены в спецификацию, и реализованы в stdlib, разве это плохо?

Comment: @monobogdan  Все правильно: некоторые. То есть если действительно возникает такая исключительная необходимость обратиться к Boost, только тогда и надо обращаться. Причем совершенно не обязательно, что это будет именно Boost. Это может быть какой-нибудь другой проект с открытым кодом.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ну, буст это же не только разные дополнения C++ но и разная рутина. Грубо говоря Boost делает stdlib C++ некоторым подобием Delphi(очень многое доступно сразу но плата - размер)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вы действительно считаете, что boost "Совершенно НЕ нужно знать"? Потому что у меня как раз в планах на будущее было как следует в нем разобраться, потому что слишком часто о нем говорят, поэтому мне казалось, что его как раз нужно знать. Например, когда речь заходит о юнит тестах, обычно его советуют.

Comment: @Matty В программировании любые знания полезны. Но это не эквивалентно тому, что обязан знать. Нужно знать C++ и уметь пользоваться его стандартными средствами. Этого многим не хватает. Что касается boost, то это скорей из области фетиша: некоторые стараются выделиться тем, что привести как можно больше различных аббревиатур, чтобы произвести впечатление на других, особенно на HR..